# What would be the best way to detect what symbol of 4 the one in the image is?

Tags: image-processing, detection

I have a board with a grid on it and each cell can have one of these "cards", **Or it can be empty.** :

[image: Card0/Blue] [image: Card1/White]

[image: Card2/Yellow][image: Card3/Gourney]

I'm already done transforming the board so I can cut out every cell **individually** but I then have to look at each cell and give it the card's value.
I tried comparing **histograms** and **template** matching, but that was relatively **bad** so I tried getting the average **HSV** value of the image and see if Hue, Saturation, and Value were within a predefined range but that also gave me some problems like sometimes a white card getting a hue of 350 and then 1.

Is there a good solution to this problem?

Comment: @Bilal Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean. Could you show me with pseudo-code or a code-snippet?

Comment: @Bilal so I should create 4 min and max values and threshhold all of them and take the one with the biggest white part?

Comment: you can't average hues. you have to average in a linear space first (RGB is sufficiently linear), then calculate. -- histograms should have done well. your pictures are distinguished by their color content (red+blue+white, red+white, yellow+white, black+white) but matching based on histogram distances needs care -- pictures look somewhat underexposed. shouldn't be too much trouble though.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz im getting the average RGB and that is converted into HSV. It was my first time trying histograms but I used multiple things to make it more accurate

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by looking at the image in [HSV colourspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and calculating the percentages of red, yellow and blue pixels in the image and making a choice accordingly. First, I looked for yellows and if I find them, it's the third image. Then I looked for blues, if I don't find any, it's the second image. Then I looked for reds and if I find any, it is the first image. Otherwise it must be the last one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def detectCard(im):
    """ Detect which of 4 cards was passed as parameter """
    nPixels = im.shape[0] * im.shape[1]
    # Convert to HSV colourspace
    HSV = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Identify yellow pixels - these will be around Hue=30, and fairly saturated
    yellowLo   = np.array([20, 50, 0], np.uint8)
    yellowHi   = np.array([40, 255, 255], np.uint8)
    yellowMask = cv.inRange(HSV, yellowLo, yellowHi)
    yellowPcnt = np.count_nonzero(yellowMask)*100/nPixels
    cv.imwrite('DEBUG-yellowMask.png', yellowMask)

    # Identify blue pixels - these will be around Hue=120, and fairly saturated
    blueLo   = np.array([110, 50, 0], np.uint8)
    blueHi   = np.array([130, 255, 255], np.uint8)
    blueMask = cv.inRange(HSV, blueLo, blueHi)
    bluePcnt = np.count_nonzero(blueMask)*100/nPixels
    cv.imwrite('DEBUG-blueMask.png',blueMask)
   
    # Identify red pixels - these will be around Hue=170..180 or Hue=0..10 and fairly saturated
    redLo   = np.array([170, 50, 0], np.uint8)
    redHi   = np.array([180, 255, 255], np.uint8)
    redMask = cv.inRange(HSV, redLo, redHi)
    redLo   = np.array([0, 50, 0], np.uint8)
    redHi   = np.array([10, 255, 255], np.uint8)
    redMask2= cv.inRange(HSV, redLo, redHi)
    redMask = np.bitwise_or(redMask, redMask2)
    redPcnt = np.count_nonzero(redMask)*100/nPixels
    cv.imwrite('DEBUG-redMask.png',redMask)

    # Share percentages with caller
    print(f' {yellowPcnt=:.2f}, {bluePcnt=:.2f}, {redPcnt=:.2f}')
   
    # Note these tests could be done sooner to avoid so much calculation 
    # If plenty of yellow pixels, return "yellow"
    if yellowPcnt > 30:
        return "yellow"
    if bluePcnt < 10:
        return "red cross on white background"
    if redPcnt > 10:
        return "red cross on blue circle"
    return "robocar"

# Main program and test driver
for i in range(1,5):
    name = f'{i}.png'
    print(f'Analysing: {name}...')
    im = cv.imread(name)
    print(f'{name}: detected as {detectCard(im)}')
```

Here are the results, if you name the input images `1.png` for top-left, `2.png` for top-right, `3.png` for bottom-left and `4.png` for bottom-right:

```
Analysing: 1.png...
 yellowPcnt=0.06, bluePcnt=14.19, redPcnt=31.91
1.png: detected as red cross on blue circle
Analysing: 2.png...
 yellowPcnt=0.00, bluePcnt=0.00, redPcnt=41.77
2.png: detected as red cross on white background
Analysing: 3.png...
 yellowPcnt=58.07, bluePcnt=0.09, redPcnt=1.26
3.png: detected as yellow
Analysing: 4.png...
 yellowPcnt=5.91, bluePcnt=18.90, redPcnt=0.37
4.png: detected as robocar
```

Comment: Of course, if you want empty squares detected, you'd have to show us what an empty square looks like...